# await account.save() isnt a function when i am trying to save after pushing an object inside wallets array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

```
 const account = await find.wallets.push({ id: message.author.id, amount: 0, date: message.createdAt})

      
 await account.save();
```

**it says, account.save() isn't a function
its working in other commands, when creating new doc
do i need to save when we push an object inside an array?**

https://sourceb.in/634a9b2be0 - full code

well, account.save works in my command file in another subcommand = open

its actually creating a new doc

const account = new Account(..)   (account is defined as the schema/model)
await account.save() works there

but its not working when i am trying to save it after using the array.push function

Comment: You should be saving the document, not the function of you pushing something to an array.

Comment: Sorry? elaborate pls

Comment: From your code i quess you should use `await find.save()` since `find` is instance of Account model returned by `Account.find(..)`.

Comment: i will try, and let you know

Comment: i did this, coz 

```const account = new Account({
        guild: message.guild.id,
        wallets: [{
id: message.author.id,
amount: 0,
date: message.createdAt
}],
      });

await account.save();```
Here its working fine

Comment: So since you did this `const find = await Account.findOne({gui...` you need to save the `find` using `find.save()`

Comment: ok so no error this time, but the db remains same, i mean no update, someone registered, without any errors it said it was added but i cant see in collections

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing your actual code. But this should work `const find = await Account.findOne(...); find.wallets.push(...); find.save();` If it doesn't you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: i have gave there my source code. full code

Comment: https://sourceb.in/634a9b2be0 here it is:

Comment: https://sourceb.in/b920644403 - updated one

Comment: This `const account = [...find.wallets, { id: message.author.id, amount: 0, date: message.createdAt}]` is nonsense. It should be `find.wallets.push({ id: message.author.id, amount: 0, date: message.createdAt})` no need to assign it to `account`

Comment: ok, actually you can see that my actual line is commented and i added this coz someone asked me to do it in discord support server.

Comment: You could do this `find.wallets = [...find.wallets, { id: message.author.id, amount: 0, date: message.createdAt}]` which is the same as `find.wallets.push({ id: message.author.id, amount: 0, date: message.createdAt})`

Answer (score 0):

This `const account = [...find.wallets, { id: message.author.id, amount: 0, date: message.createdAt}]` is nonsense. It should be `find.wallets.push({ id: message.author.id, amount: 0, date: message.createdAt})` no need to assign it to account

[Molda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284355/molda) has solved my question, thanks